# How to implement expandable view (window shade) in Android?

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to implement an expandable view which behaves like the status bar?
I've seen it in many apps, so I assume it's not too difficult :)

Comment: ask specific programming problem over here rather then saying "I Need a Program"

Comment: What is the behaviour that you have seen? Please elaborate

Comment: I want it to be expandable gradually. So the bottom edge of the layout follows your finger.

Comment: I suppose jakk means the same thing that's called "window shade" on androidpatterns.com: http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/window-shade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) might be what you're looking for.

From official docs:

> SlidingDrawer hides content out of the
>   screen and allows the user to drag a
>   handle to bring the content on screen.
>   SlidingDrawer can be used vertically
>   or horizontally. A special widget
>   composed of two children views: the
>   handle, that the users drags, and the
>   content, attached to the handle and
>   dragged with it.

Comment: Thank you. Its interesting i haven't seen this before. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are asking about [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

> A class that represents how a
>   persistent notification is to be
>   presented to the user using the
>   NotificationManager.